# How can I use grep to search only on the first line of files for a specific string?

Tags: linux, grep, search

How can I use grep to find a string in files, but only search in the first line of these files?

Comment: grep -n . file.glob | grep "^1:.*search string"

Comment: grep root <(head -1 /etc/passwd)

Comment: It's probably easiest to write a perl 1-liner to do this, otherwise it would have to be a hacky combination of head and grep.

Comment: @peterh Rather than asking the question again, it is better to flag the current question for migration there.

Comment: Is there a reason you have to use **grep**?  Rather than, say **sed** or **awk**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have implemented the comment of @Rob and succeeded to get the desired result.

Replace `string` by your string.

```
grep -Rin "string" . | grep ":1:.*string" > result.txt
```

This does a recursive case-insensitive search for `string` in the current directory and prints the line numbers. Then it searches for occurrences in files which are on line 1 and saves the output to a file called `result.txt`.

Comment: This would also find any line in which `:1:` happens to occur before `string`, no matter what line that is.  E.g., a line saying `This is it:1:st string!`.

Comment: @Kusalananda true, it'll match filenames with `:1:` in them. Most probably don't

Answer (score 11):

Two more alternatives :

### With `awk`

```
awk '{if ($0~"pattern") print $0; nextfile;}' mydir/*
```

or if your `awk` version doesn't support `nextfile` (thanks to Stéphane Chazelas for the suggestion) :

```
awk 'FNR==1{if ($0~"pattern") print $0;}' mydir/*
```

will read only the first line before switching to next file, and print it only if it matches `"pattern"`.

Advantages are that one can fine-tune both the field on which to search the pattern for (using e.g. `$2` to search on the second field only) and the output (e.g. `$3` to print the third field, or `FILENAME`, or even mix).

Note that with the `FNR` ("current input record number", i.e. line number) version you can fine-tune further the line(s) on which you want to grep : `FNR==3` for the third line, `FNR<10` for the 10 first lines, etc.  (I guess in this case, if you are dealing with very large files and your `awk` version supports it you may want to mix `FNR` with `nextfile` to improve performances.)

### With `head`, keeping filenames

```
head -n1 -v mydir/files*|grep -B1 pattern
```

`-v` option of `head` will print filenames, and option `-B1` of `grep` will print the previous line of matching lines — that is, the filenames.  If you only need the filenames you can pipe it further to `grep` :

```
head -n1 -v mydir/*|grep -B1 pattern|grep ==>
```

As noticed by don_crissti in comments, beware of filenames matching the pattern themselves, though…

Answer (score 4):

Using GNU `grep`:

```
grep -m1 ^ * |grep 'pattern'
```

recursively:

```
grep -rm1 ^ . |grep 'pattern'
```

Comment: Yes. `-m` set to STOP reading after Num matching lines so -m1 means after one line

Comment: @GalBracha please see me edit now, using `.` wouldn't really match on first line, but first non-empty lines, but with `^` it does match on first line combined with the `-m1` option.

Comment: Is `-m` a GNU extension?

Comment: @CervEd I think so. while it isn't mentioned in the [GNU grep's manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html) but that doesn't exist in the [POSIX grep's](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1p.html) switches. So that should be an extension switch.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a perl onliner to do just that

`perl -ne 'print if /MY_SEARCH_STRING/; exit' myfile.txt`

This is going to check if the keyword `MY_SEARCH_STRING` is present in the first line of the file `myfile.txt`. If you need to search in the entire file just remove `exit` from the oneliner.

Comment: Note that one needs to loop on the list of files if there are several.  That is, globbing (using wildcard, e.g. `mydirectory/*`) won't work.

Answer (score 2):

we can try with sed command too

```
sed -n '1p' filename| sed -n '/pattern/p'
```

Comment: You can even combine the two tests: `sed -n '1{/pattern/p}'`. To make it more efficient, quit immediately: `sed -n '1{/pattern/p};q'`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `find` to call `head` and `grep`:

```bsh
find . -type f -exec head -n 1 {} \; | grep -e "$pattern"
```

This outputs the first line of each regular file in the current directory or below.  This is passed to `grep` which extracts the lines that matches the pattern stored in the variable `pattern`.

Using `sed` instead:

```bsh
find . -type f -exec sed -n '/pattern/p;q' {} \;
```

This invokes `sed` for each regular file.  The `sed` expression prints the current line if it matches the pattern `pattern`.  It then immediately quits.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a (bad) example of a perl-script that would do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

foreach (@ARGV) {
    my $filename = $_;
    open my $file, '<', $filename; 
    my $line = <$file>; 
    close $file;

    print "$filename\n" if $line =~ /your-match-text/;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the list of full strings as a result, or do you want a list of files that contain the string?
This would search line number one(-n1) of shell scripts(*.sh) and collect the strings containing 'bash':

```
head -n1 *.sh | grep bash > fullstring.txt
```

fullstring.txt would contain something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#!/bin/bash
```

Comment: Beware, better use the `-q` option of `head` to prevent accidental matching against the filename.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this.
Create file finder.sh with this content.
Change parameters in the file to fit your needs.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Where to search
DIR="/path/search/dir"

# Search string
SEARCH="my-string"

FILES=$(find "$DIR" -type f)

for F in $FILES; do
   head -1 $F | grep -w "$SEARCH"
done
```

Save the file and chmod +x finder.sh

Execute ./finder.sh

Note: if you going to search in files with root privileges you need to use sudo or root user.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
$ case "$(head -n 1 < file)" in (*pattern*) echo Match ;; esac
Match
```